# DevExtreme dropdowns and Watir

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, pageobjects, devextreme

So in upgrading from DevExpress to DevExtreme, DE seems to have gone out of their way to block any automation engine but their own.
Select boxes are build as a layer of custom DIV tags with a read-only input tag in the middle.
When selected, the dropdown list is generated as a DIV list structure tied to the /body/ level of the page source.
This list unloads when the dropdown list closes.
Waitr can see and interact with the list the first time it appears on the page, but once it unloads I cannot get it to find it again.
I have tried Page Object references, native Watir dynamic references, nothing works.
Interestingly I do not get the common 'no longer attached to the DOM' error, just an empty string.
All of the workarounds from DevExpress have been deactivated or blocked.

Has anyone found a way to automate these controls besides exposed JS calls?

Select Box:

```
<div class="dx-texteditor dx-dropdowneditor-button-visible dx-widget dx-textbox dx-dropdowneditor-field-clickable dx-dropdowneditor dx-selectbox dx-validator dx-visibility-change-handler" id="Active_Y_or_N" typeof="drpdown" validations="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;required&quot;}]" value="1" items="[{&quot;Value&quot;:1.0,&quot;Text&quot;:&quot;Yes&quot;,&quot;DropDownType&quot;:&quot;Active Y or N&quot;},{&quot;Value&quot;:2.0,&quot;Text&quot;:&quot;No&quot;,&quot;DropDownType&quot;:&quot;Active Y or N&quot;}]" originalvalue="1">
    <div onclick="void(0)" class="dx-dropdowneditor-input-wrapper dx-selectbox-container">
        <div class="dx-texteditor-container">
            <input id="Active_Y_or_N_1" aria-expanded="false" role="combobox" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" readonly="" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" autocomplete="off" class="dx-texteditor-input" type="text">
            <div class="dx-placeholder dx-state-invisible" data-dx_placeholder="Select..."></div>
            <div class="dx-texteditor-buttons-container">
                <div role="button" onclick="void(0)" class="dx-widget dx-button-normal dx-dropdowneditor-button">
                <div class="dx-dropdowneditor-icon"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

List:

```
<div style="width: 212px; height: 61px; z-index: 1001; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate(264px, 365px); transition: none 0s ease 0s ; visibility: visible; opacity: 1;" class="dx-overlay-content dx-popup-normal dx-popup-draggable dx-resizable">
    <div style="height: 60px;" id="2ceea1a1-35ca-5e1d-72c1-17ca0c70daa9" class="dx-popup-content">
        <div aria-activedescendant="3cc4c726-d65a-4248-b16c-6cd8ed666d08" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" class="dx-scrollable dx-scrollview dx-scrollable-customizable-scrollbars dx-scrollable-vertical dx-scrollable-simulated dx-visibility-change-handler dx-list dx-widget dx-collection" id="2779756d-884a-7d65-dd53-5ab194255698">
            <div class="dx-scrollable-container">
                <div style="transform: translate(0px, 0px);" class="dx-scrollable-content">
                    <div class="dx-scrollview-top-pocket">
                        <div style="display: none;" class="dx-scrollview-pull-down">
                            <div class="dx-scrollview-pull-down-image"></div>
                            <div class="dx-scrollview-pull-down-indicator">
                                <div class="dx-loadindicator dx-widget">
                                    <div class="dx-loadindicator-wrapper">
                                        <div class="dx-loadindicator-content">
                                            <div class="dx-loadindicator-icon">
                                                <div class="dx-loadindicator-segment dx-loadindicator-segment7"></div>
                                                <div class="dx-loadindicator-segment dx-loadindicator-segment6"></div>
                                                <div class="dx-loadindicator-segment dx-loadindicator-segment5"></div>
                                                <div class="dx-loadindicator-segment dx-loadindicator-segment4"></div>
                                                <div class="dx-loadindicator-segment dx-loadindicator-segment3"></div>
                                                <div class="dx-loadindicator-segment dx-loadindicator-segment2"></div>
                                                <div class="dx-loadindicator-segment dx-loadindicator-segment1"></div>
                                                <div class="dx-loadindicator-segment dx-loadindicator-segment0"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="dx-loadindicator-content"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dx-scrollview-pull-down-text">
                                <div style="opacity: 1;">Pull down to refresh...</div>
                                <div style="opacity: 0;">Release to refresh...</div>
                                <div style="opacity: 0;">Refreshing...</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div onclick="void(0)" class="dx-scrollview-content">
                    <div id="3cc4c726-d65a-4248-b16c-6cd8ed666d08" aria-selected="false" role="option" class="dx-item dx-list-item dx-state-focused">
                        <div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Yes</div>
                    </div>
                    <div aria-selected="false" role="option" class="dx-item dx-list-item">
                        <div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">No</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dx-scrollview-bottom-pocket">
                    <div style="display: none;" class="dx-scrollview-scrollbottom">
                    <div class="dx-scrollview-scrollbottom-indicator">
                        <div class="dx-loadindicator dx-widget">
                            <div class="dx-loadindicator-wrapper">
                                <div class="dx-loadindicator-content">
                                    <div class="dx-loadindicator-icon">
                                        <div class="dx-loadindicator-segment dx-loadindicator-segment7"></div>
                                        <div class="dx-loadindicator-segment dx-loadindicator-segment6"></div>
                                        <div class="dx-loadindicator-segment dx-loadindicator-segment5"></div>
                                        <div class="dx-loadindicator-segment dx-loadindicator-segment4"></div>
                                        <div class="dx-loadindicator-segment dx-loadindicator-segment3"></div>
                                        <div class="dx-loadindicator-segment dx-loadindicator-segment2"></div>
                                        <div class="dx-loadindicator-segment dx-loadindicator-segment1"></div>
                                        <div class="dx-loadindicator-segment dx-loadindicator-segment0"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dx-loadindicator-content">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dx-scrollview-scrollbottom-text">Loading...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="dx-scrollable-scrollbar dx-widget dx-scrollbar-vertical dx-scrollbar-hoverable">
        <div style="transform: translate(0px, 0px); height: 58px;" class="dx-scrollable-scroll dx-state-invisible">
            <div class="dx-scrollable-scroll-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dx-scrollview-loadpanel dx-overlay dx-widget dx-visibility-change-handler dx-state-invisible dx-loadpanel">
    <div aria-hidden="true" style="width: 222px; height: 90px;" class="dx-overlay-content"></div>
</div>
```

code (one version anyway):

```
self.send("#{field}_element").div(:class => 'dx-dropdowneditor-icon').click
drpdwn = @browser.div(:class => 'dx-scrollview-content')
if drpdwn.text.include? value
  drpdwn.div(:text => value).click
else
   fail "value (#{value}) not found in list (#{self.drop_list_element.text})"
end
```

Comment: On the second load of the list, Watir can see it as existing, but not visible.

Comment: It would help to give an example of the control that you are working with and the code that reproduces the problem. Watir can work with the DevExtreme dropdowns (as you saw in [my blog post](https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2016/03/11/unhiding-the-overflowhidden-in-devextreme-select-lists/)). The example would greatly help clarify where the exact problem is.

Comment: Justin, I used your example code as one of my attempts.  it had the exact same results as mentioned above.

Comment: The source code is too large to format clearly.  is there a way to upload snapshots here?

Comment: you don't need to include entire source, just the section that is giving you trouble.  edit the question, insert the code and indent 4 or more spaces, or use {code} tags and SO will format it nicely

Comment: What is the Watir code that you are running and the exact error? I am having a hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve. Why are you trying to find the list after it has been unloaded?

Comment: I added one version of my code above.  The issue is when I try to read the list to find the item to click on, I get an empty string back.  I have multiple dropdowns on the page.  I can select the value on the first box, but when I go to the second box, I cannot access the list.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to answer because I can't see your code and I have no example. So maybe it's a wrong answer. But if your statement:

> On the second load of the list, Watir can see it as existing, but not visible.

is correct. Then you can force watir to work with not visible elements using:

```
browser.hidden(id: "your_element").click
```

Try it please.

Comment: Antesser, Thank you but this does not work, for 2 reasons that I can see.  1, this command is looking for a tag of Input, I am working with a DIV.  2, the div does not have a /hidden/  tag or property, Watir has trouble accessing it because it was unloaded from source and reloaded.

Comment: Well. It seems I can't help in that case. Good luck.